# I'm trying to inflate my custom view on system's navigation bar that shows an images and animations etc

Tags: android

I'm trying to inflate my custom view on system's navigation bar that shows an images and animations etc...so the problem is that i'm not able to set the image behind the navigation bar and because of that its hiding the view of system's navigation bar(including soft keys) in Xiaomi(android 9,API 28) device and i also tested this in honor(android 8.0.0,API 26) device and its showing my custom view(containing an image) with system's navigation bar perfectly.

I've set the flags and required layout params. below piece of code shows some important code because of which its working in some devices as mention earlier. I've tried all the possible way whichever i found but still not found the solution.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lpNavView = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lpNavView.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
lpNavView.height = navBarSize; 
  
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        lpNavView.type = 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
        lpNavView.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL 
| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS | 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION;
        lpNavView.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;

    } else {
        lpNavView.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
        lpNavView.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL 
| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS| 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION;
        lpNavView.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

mWindowManager.addView(mNavBarView, lpNavView);
```

Are there any flags to set my view behind the system's navigation bar? or some other way for this problem.

Image contain custom navigation bar in Xiaomi device

[image: Image contain custom navigation bar in Xiaomi device]

Comment: You have to use a simple service. Initially i was making a view in an Accessibility service and because of that some of the devices may not support such views created in Accessibility service.